# How do I specify the version of asp.net for web project

Tags: asp.net

How do I specify the version of asp .net for my web project?  I cannot figure how to specify it nor can I figure out what version it assumes by default.

Answer (score 1):

You can select it when creating a new project from Visual Studio.

Your project template comes from updating visual studio and installing the asp version from http://getasp.net

Comment: I inherited this web project so I have no idea what was specified by the original author.   How can I tell what the project is build against?

Comment: @DonGolden: Look in Project Properties and in Web.config.